# Angular user creation process

Tags: javascript, angular.js, firebase

I've written 3 factories as a part of a sign up process in AngularJS and Firebase. After completing them, I thought to myself, would any of these fit better as a service instead of a factory? From my research it's a bit fuzzy when it comes to choosing whether to create a service or a factory. If so, why would they fit better as a service? How can I tell when to create a service and when to create a factory?

I've documented the `methods` to explain what they do, and the ones that lack a documentation explains themselves in the `key` name.

```
forumApp.factory('fbRef', ['$firebase', '$firebaseAuth', function($firebase, $firebaseAuth) {

    return {
        getReference: function(path) {
            return path ? new Firebase('https://mydbname.firebaseio.com/' + path) : new Firebase('https://forum-app.firebaseio.com');  
        },
        getSyncedReference: function(path) {
            return $firebase(this.getReference(path));
        },
        getAuthObj: function(path) {
            return $firebaseAuth(this.getReference(path));
        }
    };
}]);

forumApp.factory('validation', [function() {

    /**
     * Validate user input before any database entries
     *
     * @param String $input
     *  Unvalidated input.
     *
     * @return Boolean
     *  True -> Input passed validation.
     *  False -> Input faulty, return error
     */
    return {
        validateSignup: function(user) {

            for (var info in user) {
                if (user[info] === '') {
                    return 'All fields must be filled in';
                }
            }

            if (user.age > 99) {
                return 'Sorry grandma, you are too old for this forum';
            }
            else if (isNaN(user.age)) {
                return 'Age only allows digits';
            }
            else if (user.email === undefined) {
                return 'Invalid email format';
            }
            else if (user.password != user.confirmedPassword) {
                return 'The passwords do not match';
            }
            else if (user.isTermsAccepted === false) {
                return 'You must accept the terms and service agreement';
            }
        }
    }
}]);

forumApp.factory('dbEntry', ['$firebase', 'fbRef', '$location', function($firebase, fbRef, $location) {
    return {
        /**
         * Insert user details into Firebase
         *
         * @param Object(s) user, userData 
         *  User details, user ID
         *
         * @return Boolean
         *  True -> Successful database entry
         *  False -> Unsuccessful database entry
         */
        insertUserDetails: function(user, userData) {

            return fbRef.getSyncedReference(userData.uid).$set({
                firstname: user.firstname,
                lastname: user.lastname,
                age: user.age,
                country: user.country,
                displayName: user.displayName,
                email: user.email
            }).then(function() {
                return true;
            }, function(error) {
                return false;
            });
        },
        /**
         * Create a new user account in Firebase
         *
         * @param Object user
         *  User details
         *
         * @return String
         *  If error -> error message
         *  If successful:
         *    -> store user details
         *    -> change location hash to homepage
         */
        createNewUser: function(user) {
            var self = this;

            return fbRef.getAuthObj().$createUser({
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password
            }).then(function(userData) {

                var isDetailsStored = self.insertUserDetails(user, userData);
                    isDetailsStored ? $location.path('/home') : this.removeUser(user);
            }).catch(function(error) {

                switch (error.code) {
                    case 'EMAIL_TAKEN': 
                        return 'Email already registered';

                    default: 
                        return 'Connection error - try again later';
                }
            });
        },
        /**
         * Remove the newly-created user if
         * details entry failed to force
         * the user to sign up again
         *
         * @param Object user
         *  User details
         *
         * @return Boolean
         *  True -> User removal successful
         *  False -> User removal unsuccessful
         */
        removeUser: function(user) {

            return fbRef.getAuthObj().$removeUser({
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password
            }).then(function() {
                return true;
            }).catch(function(error) {
                return false;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be misinterpreting what a "factory" does in programming.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

> In class-based programming, the factory method pattern is a creational pattern which uses factory methods to deal with the problem of **creating objects without specifying the exact class of object that will be created.** This is done by creating objects via calling a factory method—either specified in an interface and implemented by child classes, or implemented in a base class and optionally overridden by derived classes—rather than by calling a constructor.

Basically, a "factory" class or method replaces this code:

```
var x = new Foo();
```

With:

```
var x = SomeFactory.getInstance(/* args */);
```

So the code using the `x` variable doesn't have to know its concrete type.

Your code is making web service calls implementing business logic rather than being a fancy wrapper for `new Foo()`.

From the accepted answer for [Difference between a service class and a Helper class](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/132138/118878) at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com):

> A Service class/interface provides a way of a client to interact with some functionality in the application. This is typically public, with some business meaning. For example, a TicketingService interface might allow you to buyTicket, sellTicket and so on.

Your code has "business meaning" -- it manages users in the system -- and therefore is a service. I would register it with AngularJS accordingly.

#### How AngularJS Defines (And Confuses) Services and Factories

The frustrating thing about the AngularJS documentation is the code examples in the [AngularJS Services Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) keep using `myModule.factory(...)` to create a service. This creates some confusion on the roles of services and factories.

From the AngularJS docs:

```
myModule.factory('serviceId', function() {
    // ...
});
```

Two things are happening here.

1. A **factory function** is registered with the framework that will return an object for a dependency named `serviceId`
2. The **object returned** by the factory function **is the service object**.

Your use of `forumApp.factory(...)` is the correct way to create services in AngularJS. The end result of `forumApp.factory(...)` is a factory function that returns your service objects. Yes, you have created 3 factories, but those factories then create services --- and this is the correct pattern.

This StackOverflow question is a good read: [angularjs - Service vs provider vs factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory)

Comment: Hmm, I see. This was the best explanation I've seen so far on this, will change them accordingly!

Comment: I added some additional info about services and factories in AngularJS. There is a lot of confusion about how they interact.